# re.sub() in Python does not always work while replacing currency values in string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text-mining

I have built a "Currency Tagger" in Python which identifies all currency expressions and replaces them with a tagged string.

Example,
replace `"I have $20 in my pocket"`
with `"I have <Currency>$20</Currency> in my pocket"`

One of the tasks requires me to substitute the string identified as Currency with the tagged string. I am using `re.sub()` to do this.

It works perfectly for every form of string except of the form "$4.4B" or "$4.4M".

I tried running simple example in my python console and found that `re.sub()` works inconsistently with patterns which have a mixed dollar pattern.

For example,

```
>>> text = "I have #20 in my pocket"
>>> re.sub("#20", "$20", text)
'I have $20 in my pocket'
>>> text = "I have $20 in my pocket"
>>> re.sub("$20", "#20", text)
'I have $20 in my pocket'
```

In the above example you see that when I am trying to replace "$20" with "#20" it does not work (in the second case).

Any help would be greatly appreciated of course. A very silly bug has cropped up and is stalling major work because of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` is a `special character` .So if you want to replace it use

```
 re.sub(r"\$20", "#20", text)

          ^^
```

You will have to `escape` it.Also use `r` mode to avoid `escaping` problems.

`$` means end of string.So your regex was being ineffective.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `re.escape('$20')` which can make the regex a little easier to read in some circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using regular expressions (and you don't seem to be), there is no reason to use the "re" module.

Just use the .replace() method of strings:

```
text.replace("#20", "$20")
```